# Equivalent to sp_refreshview in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Does Oracle has something like sp_refreshview on SQL Server?

Thanks in advance,
Goran

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle there is an equivalent, but it's not necessary to use it. Here is an example:

A table:

```
SQL> create table t (id,name)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'StackOverflow' from dual
  4  /

Table created.
```

A view:

```
SQL> create view v
  2  as
  3  select id
  4       , name
  5    from t
  6  /

View created.
```

Which is valid:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from v
  3  /

        ID NAME
---------- -------------
         1 StackOverflow

1 row selected.

SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
VALID

1 row selected.
```

Now do something to the underlying table:

```
SQL> alter table t add (description varchar2(100))
  2  /

Table altered.
```

Since Oracle stores dependencies (see the DBA/ALL/USER_DEPENDENCIES views), the view is marked as invalid:

```
SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
INVALID

1 row selected.
```

But you can still select from it. Oracle tries to execute it anyway, even if it knows the view is marked INVALID:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from v
  3  /

        ID NAME
---------- -------------
         1 StackOverflow

1 row selected.
```

And by selecting from the view, it has marked the view VALID again:

```
SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
VALID

1 row selected.
```

You can also compile the view, to be sure the view is valid in advance:

```
SQL> alter table t add (description2 varchar2(100))
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
INVALID

1 row selected.

SQL> alter view v compile
  2  /

View altered.
```

"Compiling" the view marks it as valid:

```
SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
VALID

1 row selected.
```

If the change affects the view in such a way that the underlying query cannot execute anymore:

```
SQL> alter table t drop column name
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
INVALID

1 row selected.
```

Then you'll get a runtime error:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from v
  3  /
  from v
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-04063: view "OWNER.V" has errors


SQL> select status
  2    from user_objects
  3   where object_name = 'V'
  4  /

STATUS
-------
INVALID

1 row selected.
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Disagree. It is neccessary. That is the problem with start-views. You add columns to the underlying tables. The views stay valid but the new columns are not included. And this is what causes a lot of headage to our support.

Comment: I don't think using a * in a view is a particularly good idea.  You may end up with things in there you didn't intend.

Comment: @bernd_k: If you add a column to a table which you want included in the view as well, then you should explicitly include the new column in the view. I also think that "select *" for a view definition is not a good idea. It can lead to unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Here we are not discussing best practise, but a feature which is supported by MS-SQLServer and is not supported by ORACLE.

Comment: +1, although the short answer to OP's question is: "alter view v compile"

Comment: @ DCookie. That makes an invalid view valid, but doesn't add new columns. I never tried, what happens when a column is removed.

Comment: @JONT Too true it is bas practice. Someone might add a CLOB column and someon else uses Select * from v1 union Select * from v2 and you are forced to use explicit column list. But when it is in the Database you can either acomodate with the facts or look for a new job

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know not. And I usually see for views like select * from the only the expanded form saved in the database. I think there is no chance that you can add a column to an underlying table and get this column into the view than altering the view.

For the ORACLE users here the example what you can do with SQL-Server (since SQL2008), but the unmodified definition was stored in syscomments in sysbase times as well:

**Warning this is T-SQL**

```
create table t1 (i int, c1 int);
create view v1 as select * from t1;
alter table t1 add c2 int;
select * from v1;   -- c2 is not present here
sp_refreshview v1;
select * from v1;   -- c2 is present here
```

I guess as Oracle doesn't store the definition, it can't refresh the view.